# Is there any way to reduce admob's full-page ad loading time?

Tags: admob

My react native App code:

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync({
    servePersonalizedAds: true
  }).then(() => {
    this.setState({
      admobLoading: true
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    this.setState({
      admobLoading: true
    });
  });
}

render() {
  if (!this.state.admobLoading) return null;
  SplashScreen.hide();
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Main>{AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync()}</Main>
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

My app loads admob ads from the splash screen. 
When the load is complete, exit the splash screen, show the full-page advertisement and go to the main page.
But it takes too long to load an ad-mob ad.
For my app, it takes 5 to 15 seconds, and users are uncomfortable with it.
Is there any way to reduce the load time?